# How to decode string address into Pubkey address on Solana

Tags: python, typescript, solana

I am querying data from raydium using their SDK, but i am trying to do it in Python instead.
So, I am obtaining an address:

```
<BN: b870e12dd379891561d2e9fa8f26431834eb736f2f24fc2a2a4dff1fd5dca4df>
```

And I know it correspond to :

```
PublicKey(DQyrAcCrDXQ7NeoqGgDCZwBvWDcYmFCjSb9JtteuvPpz)]
```

But anyone know how one could decode the first into the second please, so i could implement this in Python.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Solana use `base58` for encode address. In python, you can use module `base58` to encode from hex string address.

```
import base58

hex_sting="b870e12dd379891561d2e9fa8f26431834eb736f2f24fc2a2a4dff1fd5dca4df"

byte_string = bytes.fromhex(hex_sting)

encoded_string = base58.b58encode(byte_string).decode() # DQyrAcCrDXQ7NeoqGgDCZwBvWDcYmFCjSb9JtteuvPpz
```